# Why does the music in the game "Oh, Deer!" work in 16.04 but not 18.04?

Tags: sound, 18.04, games, libraries

So, I got an indie game (Oh, Deer!) from Humble Store and while using Lubuntu 16.04, its music worked flawlessly. However, when I installed 18.04, game refused to launch unless I installed `libmad0` from terminal.

Did it. The game opens but the main music stops, so I uninstalled `libmad` via terminal and downloaded it from source, compiled and installed it. And the same problem persists.
It worked well on 16.04, so I don't know if 18.04 needs to install some dependencies to get the music to work.

It's an `.appimage` file, btw.

I got the windows version just to see the files and saw that the music  files from the game are all `.ogg` files. Tried to install ogg related libraries but it didn't work as well.

I could contact Humble Store, but I believe this is a problem on 18.04. Anyone could give me a light on this problem?

Comment: What game is it?

Comment: Hi, Oh, Deer! is the name. The main music stops when racing starts.

Comment: I've edited your question for you to make it clearer and help others to find you an answer. Can you run the `.appimage` file in the terminal and post the output here? From your details, the issue is unlikely to lie with the ogg/vorbis codec (it's included in Ubuntu). Installing extra libraries in that case would just add bloat to your system, but not help you solve your problem, unfortunately.

Comment: No problem, thanks, this is the output it show while running the game:
https://pastebin.com/1uvEmEVJ

Answer (score 1):

so, I found a 'fix' for this issue.

I have an Optimus laptop. It's a bug after installing Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu. When you install nvidia prime for the first time and then reboot, Nvidia is the default profile. Then if you want to play "Oh, Deer!", the music suddenly stops.

The fix is, change your nvidia profile to Intel, logout, change it back to Nvidia, logout and just play the game again, then the bug goes away. The music is working flawlessly now.